# Identifying mushrooms through deep learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I need to write a program that recognizes mushroom species using deep learning. So far I have 26 mushroom folders, approx. 500 photos per species. The problem is that it receives a maximum efficiency of about 45%. Does anyone know what I could improve or what layers to put in the model to improve the quality?
Link to the photo database: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ebj5GVSGrqa-B4F5RNEbyTrr7xM2a7U-?usp=sharing

```
import keras.losses
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pathlib

def create_model():
    num_classes = len(train_ds.class_names)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1. / 255),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
    ])
    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )
    return model

def load_data():
    data_dir = pathlib.Path("Mushrooms")
    image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*')))
    train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        data_dir,
        validation_split=0.2,
        subset="training",
        seed=123,
        image_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=batch_size
    )

    val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        data_dir,
        validation_split=0.2,
        subset="validation",
        seed=123,
        image_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=batch_size
    )
    return train_ds, val_ds

# hyperparams
batch_size = 32
img_height = 100
img_width = 100
epochs = 12

train_ds, val_ds = load_data()
model = create_model()
#model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model')

history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=epochs
)

acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']

loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs_range = range(epochs)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.show()

model.save("model", overwrite=True, save_format='tf')
```

Comment: This might be a better question for [datascience.se] as it doesn't pertain to specific code-related questions or problems

Comment: cnn are filters for specific features.   you may need other types of classifiers to improve recognition.

Comment: Double the number of conv2d filters after each maxpooling, that is `Conv2D(32, ...`, `Conv2D(64, ...`, `Conv2D(128, ...`. You could use 2 conv2d layers before each maxpooling. Since you don't have that much data, you should add some data augmentation: rotation, change of brightness, some noise, etc.

Comment: The download in the link doesn't work

Comment: Use transfer learning to build a model on top of a pretrained model - check https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/

Comment: Sorry for the link, I've already changed it.